# Preg_match_all() get new lines PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to get all the data for a pipped email so I can place the strings into a file & save it as a base64.

Here is some sample of the file:

```
--089e0158c026b67091050f58bd9c--
--089e0158c026b6709a050f58bd9e
Content-Type: audio/mpeg; name="test.mp3"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.mp3"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: f_i6agw8nv0

SUQzBAAAAAABKlRYWFgAAAAZAAADV01GU0RLTmVlZGVkADAuMC4wLjAwMDAAVFhYWAAAAB4AAANE
ZXZpY2VDb25mb3JtYW5jZVRlbXBsY
XRlAEwxAFRYWFgAAAAfAAADV01GU0RLVmVyc2lvbgAxMi4w
```

However my code is only picking up the first line until a return character is used.  I am trying to find a way to get all return characters all the way to the end of the string.

Here is my code I have tried so far:

```
    preg_match_all("/X-Attachment-Id:\s(.*)/i", $email, $matches);
```

I've been searching & searching but have hit a dead wall. I've seen some say to use /s & others to use /e, but where & how for applying to my search is where I am unsure.

If someone can kindly give me a little advice on how to do this regular expression it would help me a lot! (I'm pretty new to regular expressions.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get? The contents of the header is just a single line in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
preg_match_all("/X-Attachment-Id:\s([^µ]*)/i", $email, $matches);
```

I know it is a little bit dirty, but it works.

Best Way would be:

```
preg_match_all("/X-Attachment-Id:\s(.*)/si", $email, $matches);
```

Notice the 's' after delimiter, this is the regex option you are talking about
You can combine it with 'i' anothers

Comment: Oh that worked Great!  I still had to do a little more manipulating of the string to get the pure base64 content, but your code did a great job! I was just misplacing the location for the s.. THANKS!